# Flow complaining about incompatible type in object default values destructuring

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have this very simple function I'm trying to validate with Flow:

```
// @flow
type Props = {
  width: string | number,
};

function fun({
  width = '30em',
}: Props) {
  return width;
}
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
8:   width = '30em',
     ^ number. This type is incompatible with
8:   width = '30em',
     ^ string
8:   width = '30em',
     ^ string. This type is incompatible with
8:   width = '30em',
     ^ number
8:   width = '30em',
             ^ string. This type is incompatible with
8:   width = '30em',
     ^ number
```

I wonder what I'm doing wrong... This other way works fine:

```
// @flow
type Props = {
  width: string | number,
};

function fun(props: Props) {
  const {
    width = '30em',
  } = props;
  return width;
}
```

And this syntax inside function arguments seem supported because:

```
// @flow
type Props = {
  width: string,
};

function fun({ width = '30em' }: Props) {
  return width;
}
```

This works just fine.

Ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/183

Comment: If that was the problem, it should throw error even on my second example. Also, it should throw a syntax error. Also, it works with a single type .

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug. If you don't think it's the same one as Jared has linked to then please log another.

Comment: I did already [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4270)

Answer (score 0):

[Destructuring default assignment is not supported in Flow.](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/881)

Rather than assigning defaults and destructuring at the same time, you should define defaultProps separately, then use those as your defaults.

For example:

```
type Props = {
    width: string | number
}

const defaultProps: Props = {
    width: '30em',
}

function fun ({ width }: Props = defaultProps) {
  return width
}

fun({ width: 30 })   // => 30
fun({ width: '30' }) // => '30'
fun()                // => '30em'

fun({ width: true }) // $ExpectError
```

Here is a [working example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKATnDgM5gC8YA3qgJAICWAJhgBYBcY5GxzAHYBzMAB8wggK4BbAEZ5iqAL7oAxnEF8wrPFACGUmBhJlyPUxWp1GLdtzAByAMwAGPDMcAaFeihTBNQxmTTB-QTAAClowO04wZQtSKxpdAyMTZPIAShswMGI8DCliCLiOX1Rw6Ni2Th43BOyqgJrynhdXRyaWwUjm3ra6h34pAmVc4GAwABIAUQAPfCC54lJiIA).

Comment: Mine is a function. Not a React component

Comment: Yes, I realize this. I'm unsure as to your point. You use "type = Props" in your type definition, so I defined a const "defaultProps". Please provide more explanation as to the downvote, as this is a working solution to your problem.

Comment: if your goal is to use destructuring default assignment, as far as I can tell this is not supported in flow.  https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/881

Comment: You are just repeating things mentioned in my question and in the comments. That's the point.

Comment: De structuring default assignment is now supported, because my second example works just fine. And my third example is a simple variant of your "solution". How can you say you aren't repeating existing informations? The URL you provided was already in the comments.

Comment: 1. your third example works because it's just width = string. there is no union type. 2. in my comment I should have said "destructuring default parameter assignment is not supported." so I did misspeak. 3. the third example is not a variant. in it you do not do destructuring of parameters, which I thought was your goal. what is your goal btw? 4. I linked to issue 881. You linked to issue 183.

Answer (score 0):

You can try typing the entire function instead of the Props specifically:

```
const fun: (Props) => string | number = ({
  width = '30em',
}) => {
  return width;
}
```

What you're observing has been a bug for quite some time. See [issue 2198](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2198).